# Convert uint8_t array to uint16_t

Tags: c

I have a uint8_t array that contains two elements:

```
uint8_t ui8[2]; // uint8_t array
ui8[0] = 70; // LSB
ui1[1] = 60; // MSB
```

I want to get a uint16_t number (not an array) from these two uin8_t values. I used this approach in order to get this result: `uint16_t ui16 = 6070`

```
uint16_t ui16 = ui8[1] | (ui8[0] << 8);
```

But I got `uint16_t ui16 = 15430;`

Am using the wrong method to get what I need? Or is there something missing?

Comment: Why would you get 6070 (or should that be 7060?)? Whence did 100 come?

Comment: @Biffen I don't understand why should it be 7060 ? Let's say that I have a this number 6070, it's an uint16_t and I need to copy it to another variable but I have a function that only takes uint8_t types. What should I do in this case ? My idea is to make an array that contains two elements: 70 and 60 and then append them to get the uint16_t value.

Comment: 60 * 256 + 70 = 15430

Comment: @zerocoldTUN I was thinking 7060 because you have 70 in `ui8[0]` and 60 in `ui8[1]`, but nevermind, it seems you want to use little-endian. What’s still unclear though is why you want to make *decimal* operations. If you think of the 8-bit values as binary ‘halves’ of the 16-bit value then 60 and 70 ‘concatenated’ become 15430.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you meant to work with hexadecimal numbers :

```
uint8_t ui8[2]; // uint8_t array
ui8[0] = 0x70; // LSB
ui1[1] = 0x60; // MSB

uint16_t ui16 = ui8[1] | (ui8[0] << 8);
printf("%x\n", ui16); // 7060
```

---

If you want to work with decimal number, when you need to multiply the "MSB" by 100 and add them. It's far more uncommon to work with decimal number for that.

```
uint8_t ui8[2]; // uint8_t array
ui8[0] = 70; // LSB
ui1[1] = 60; // MSB

uint16_t ui16 = ui8[1] + (ui8[0] * 100);
printf("%d\n", ui16); // 7060
```

---

Please not than in both case, "70" will be before the "60", because you're shifting the first element of the array (70). The 70 will be the MSB.

Comment: Also note the code should cast the `uint8_t` value to `uint16_t` before shifting it. Otherwise, a `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int`, which could be 16 bits, in which case the shift could overflow, which has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

you can also use union punning for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
    uint8_t u8[2];
    uint16_t u16;
}data16;

int main() {
    data16 d16;

    d16.u8[0] = 0x60;
    d16.u8[1] = 0x70;

    printf("%hx\n", d16.u16);

    // it works in the opposite direction as well
    // lets try to store 7060 decimal in two bytes

    d16.u16 = 7060u;

    printf("storing %hu decimal in two bytes: LSB:0x%0hhx (%hhu decimal), MSB:0x%0hhx (%hhu decimal)\n", d16.u16, d16.u8[0], d16.u8[0], d16.u8[1], d16.u8[1]);

    return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t ui8[2]; // uint8_t array
ui8[0] = 70; // LSB
ui1[1] = 60; // MSB
```

To copy the both values into a uint16, you can do as below:

```
uint16_t output = 0;
output |= (uint16_t)ui8[0] << 8;
output |= (uint16_t)ui8[1] << 0;
```

You can use the similar logic for writing the uint32_t/uint64_t from the array of uint8_t.